# Jquery not accessing the content of one of the form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following pattern of div id's defined in my code. Please take a look at it:

```
<div id="wideWrapper">
 <div id="divContentFrame">
    <div class="ContentContainer">
            <cfform id="someid" action="" method="post">
                <input class="noDisplay" name="token" id="sCsrfToken" value="" type="hidden">
            <div id="messageInfoWrap">
                <div class="messageInfo">
                <div class="messageInfoFields ">
                    <div class="field required">
                    <label for="subject">From Address:<span class="indicator">*</span></label>
                    <input name="inpKey" id="inpKey" value="" type="text">
                    </div>


    and so on....
                        </div> // for messageInfoWrap



            <div class="messageInfoFields referenceName">
                <div class="field required">
                <label for="refname">Function Name:</label>
                <input name="sRefName" id="inputDescription" type="text">

                <span class="border"></span>
                 <span class="arrow right"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
```

In jquery function call, I am trying to access the content of From Address field in the following manner:

```
 $("#divContentFrame #inppKey").val(d.DATA.CURRinpkey[0]);
```

But it's not picking up the content. Am I doing something wrong here?

Because the same thing when I am doing for another form field like:

`$("#divContentFrame #inputDescription").val()` it's working fine.

Comment: Hmm, I am wondering it still worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divContentFrame #inpKey").val();
```

not

```
$("#divContentFrame #inpKey").val;
```

Comment: Yeah, but I am accessing another function over there like `$("#divContentFrame #inppKey").val(d.DATA.CURRinpkey[0]);` I have updated my question

Comment: @Jack by passing a value into .val() you are setting the value, not getting it. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The use of two selectors here is unecessary and adds unecessary overhead.  You also misspelled inpKey as inppKey.  Use

```
$("#inpKey").val()
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any issue other than the missing closing tag for input.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9aBAB/4/) your code just works fine.

```
    <div id="wideWrapper">
     <div id="divContentFrame">
      <div class="ContentContainer">
       <div id="messageInfoWrap">
        <div class="messageInfo">
         <div class="messageInfoFields ">
          <div class="field required">
           <input name="inpKey" id="inpKey" value="" type="text"/>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>


    $("#divContentFrame #inpKey").val('test');
```

And isn't d.DATA.CURRinpkey[0] an object?!

Comment: Hmm probably there is something wrong with flow of my ajax calls. I'll dicsuss about it in my other related post. Thanks